# google indexes URLs with ?m=1 ending on blogger

Tags: indexing, blogger

who can we fix it!

Hello I have blogger with (https://ezzeddinisalm.blogspot.com) and before two days I bought new domain from google ([islamink.com](http://islamink.com)) and connected it (same blog) with using redirect 301 but on the new domain Google **indexes** `?m=1` as in the image bellow

[image]

and when I try to inspect the same link by myself without ?m=1 I get Discovered - currently not indexed

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "you get discovered"? For me, both links you posted work.

Answer (score 0):

?m=1 added in permalink when you load a page from mobile device. You cannot remove ?m=1 , but you can hide it using javascript code
Add Following code in  section of your template :

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
<!-- Code From narendradwivedi.org -->
//<![CDATA[
var uri = window.location.toString();
if (uri.indexOf("%3D","%3D") > 0) {
var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("%3D"));
window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
}
var uri = window.location.toString();
if (uri.indexOf("%3D%3D","%3D%3D") > 0) {
var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("%3D%3D"));
window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
}
var uri = window.location.toString();
if (uri.indexOf("&m=1","&m=1") > 0) {
var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("&m=1"));
window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
}
var uri = window.location.toString();
if (uri.indexOf("?m=1","?m=1") > 0) {
var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("?m=1"));
window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
}
//]]>
</script>
```

When you are submitting url in google search console, make sure to remove ?m=1
Discovered - Currently not indexed means google know that url but due to duplicate content / copy paste posts , not allowing to index the page. Sometime google consider your post as less important , so you get discovered - currently not indexed in search console. Try resubmitting those posts again after your site have some good quality posts.

Reference : [Narendra Dwivedi - Remove ?m=1 From URL](https://www.narendradwivedi.org/2020/11/remove-m-1-from-blogger.html)